# How to Have User Specify Run Location of Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a multi-purpose macro workbook with a bunch of different macros attached to various buttons.  I would then like the user to be able to click a certain button and then be able to select the page on a different workbook they want that particular macro to run on.  I'm thinking to create a message box prompt to guide the user to dynamically select the active window they want before the macro runs.

Is this possible?  The active window changes every time the user presses the macro button on the first page so I'm thinking some specifying code around the prompt would be the answer.

```
Sub hr_test()
Dim fileBrowse As FileDialog
Dim shtNum As Integer
Set fileBrowse = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
If fileBrowse.Show = True Then wbPath = fileBrowse.SelectedItems(1)
With Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
    shtNum = InputBox("Enter the number of the sheet you want to use.")
    Sheets(shtNum).Activate

    Range("$A$1:$R$6523").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    "=Global Commercial Services-Global 1", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:= _
    "=Global Commercial Services-Global 2"
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C4135").Select
Columns("M:M").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("M1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("Q:R").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("R4130").Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why does the active window change? Usually you'd just have it work on the sheet the user made active.

Comment: It's hard to read the code you provided.

Comment: please provide the code you have and we can help you a lot more to work with your desired solution.

Comment: What code would I need to write for user to specify the macro code to run on with a click of the active window they want to use?

Comment: Oh - are you using buttons on a worksheet to run the macros? Better to use the Ribbon or even the macros dialog.

Comment: ok I've added the code I've borrowed from another page on here and it's working!  The only problem I now have is regarding hidden sheets.  I know Sheets.Visible = True is a property related to my question but I just don't know where to put it in the code.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your workbooks are open:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim r As Range, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
   Set r = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Make a pick", Type:=8)
   MsgBox "You picked sheet " & r.Parent.Name & " of Workbook " & r.Parent.Parent.Name
End Sub
```

Select the workbook and worksheet and click on any cell in that worksheet.

Comment: I think its worth noting that the you would most likely want to add set the `wb` and `ws` variables based on r as well and then reference the rest of the macro off the `wb` and `ws` where appropriate.